# sys.exit() GCP Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Have written GCP Cloud Function in Python 3.7. While executing, `sys.exit()` I'm getting 'A server error occurred ...'.  I need to exit out of the function and have written following code.

```
import sys 
if str(strEnabled) == 'True':
        printOperation = "Operation: Enabling of user" 
else:
        sys.exit() #Exit From the Program
```

Please suggest, what I'm missing here.

Comment: Use `return` instead of `sys.exit`

Comment: Your cloud function starts life with an HTTP request. It should return an HTTP status when the HTTP request is finished. Calling `exit()` is considered an exception, which means your code crashed. By calling `return` instead, your code is returning a success status (HTTP 200).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `return` instead of `sys.exit`

*<sub>Copied from [bigbounty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6849682/bigbounty)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090501/sys-exit-gcp-cloud-function#comment111565762_63090501)</sub>*

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. Any reason by sys.ext() is not working in GCP CF environment. –

Comment: @Rakesh Well `return` just exits the function, but `sys.exit()` exits the Python interpreter by raising `SystemExit`. I haven't used GCP myself, but I bet it wraps your function in some kind of exception-handling, and it's not expecting you to try to exit the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a function from another function and needs to directly exit from the inner function without `return` you can use `abort`.

`abort` will directly return the response and exit the program from the place you are calling it.

```
import sys 
from flask import abort

if str(strEnabled) == 'True':
    printOperation = "Operation: Enabling of user" 
else:
    # abort(200) #return 200
    abort(500, description="Exit") #return 500
```

> Note: cloud functions use flask module internally, so you need not
> install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone else stumbling on this question, I found that raising an exception is the easiest way to exit out of a python cloud function if you can't easily return normally (as from an inner nested function that fails):

`raise Exception("Something went wrong - exiting")`

This will log an error, exit gracefully and avoid the instance running until timeout.